# Using string to create table in JPA2 (similar to JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc, jpa-2.0

Using JDBC, I can use a String to create the schema of a table:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION " +
               "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
               " first VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " age INTEGER, " + 
               " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Is there a way to specify a table in JPA2 using a String?

EDIT:

In case this is not clear: I mean instead of creating an `@Entity` class to represent my table. I want to use a `String` the way I would in `JDBC`.

Comment: By specify a table, I am assuming you mean 'create a table'. Are you using Hibernate in your project? It can be configured to create tables if they are not already present on application startup

Comment: @Chetter Hummin I change `specify` to `create` -- although the code snippet already made it obvious. See my additional note concerning your mention of hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Have you looked at JPQL? A good intro is at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-jpql-087123.html

Comment: @Chetter Hummin Thanks for the link. I am going to look at it. Particularly I am thinking of using `ObjectDB`. But I assume that details makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

No. JPA does not provide any way to define tables (or corresponding things in non-relational databases).

JPA handles the specification of data organisation through entity classes; you write and annotate classes which model the data. A JPA provider may then provide some means of setting up the underlying store to match the entities, but this is not standardised.

Comment: The underlying database I am trying to use is `ObjectDB`. Do you know of any jpa providers who provide this?

Comment: If not JPA, do you know if JDO allows this?

Comment: With ObjectDB, i believe you don't need to explicitly create anything. You just open a connection and start persisting objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can do this by code. Tables can not be created created if doesn't exist. Most of the applications use existing databases.

You can use eclipseLink (if you use) that can create the schema for you. Read this page [EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL) to know how to enable this feature

The followings you need to specify in your `persistence.xml`

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name"
     value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
<property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" 
       value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
```